# How to unnest lists in a list into a list?

Tags: r, list, function, transformation, rbind

Consider the minimal working example

```
raw_list <- list(1, 2)
process_list <- function(item) {
    if(item == 1) {
        return(list(c(1, 1), c(2, 2)))
    }
    else {
        return(c(3, 3))
    }
}

processed_list <- lapply(raw_list, process_list)

df <- do.call(rbind, processed_list)
```

`processed_list` is

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2 2


[[2]]
[1] 3 3
```

and `df` is

```
     [,1]      [,2]     
[1,] numeric,2 numeric,2
[2,] 3         3
```

How do I unnest `processed_list` to get

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 3
```

or how do I unnest `df` to get

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should also `list` the `c(3, 3)` in the function, then `unlist` non-recursively.

```
raw_list <- list(1, 2)

process_list <- function(item) {
  if(item == 1) {
    return(list(c(1, 1), c(2, 2)))
  }
  else {
    return(list(c(3, 3)))
  }
}

processed_list <- lapply(raw_list, process_list)

unlist(processed_list, recursive=FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply use

```
simple_list <- unlist(processed_list, recursive = FALSE)
```

and then simply

```
df <- do.call(rbind, simple_list)
```

this gives:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 3
```

and

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    3
[4,]    3    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
processed_list[[2]] <- list(processed_list[[2]])

processed_list <- processed_list |> unlist(recursive = FALSE)

df <- do.call(rbind, processed_list)
```